# Shoud JAVA_HOME variable contain quotes if points to path with spaces?

Tags: windows, java-home

My JDK is located at

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`

Should JAVA_HOME contain

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`

or

`"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131"`

?

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes using the absolute path like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131` can cause some ambiguity while installing a tool or running a script where `JAVA` is needed. So, using double quotes for the path is a wise choice.

Also, you can set the `JAVA_HOME` path in the following ways if it contains space:

```
C:\Program~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_131

Progra~1 = 'Program Files'
Progra~2 = 'Program Files(x86)'
```

Comment: Just to reiterate, correct one is `Progra~1` not `Program~1`. Couldn't edit the answer because of min 6 characters rule.